# Python & Windows: Where is the python launcher?

Tags: python

I'm trying to use different versions of `python` on `win7`, and I was told that I can use the `python laucher`.

I find the docs for it: https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#launcher
But I don't know where is it. Someone say its called `py.exe`, but there is no file with this name on my computer.

I installed python `3.4.3` with `Anaconda`, https://store.continuum.io/cshop/anaconda/, comes with `Scipy`

===========

UPDATE:
Since there is no `python launcer` in `Anacoda`, how can I re-install it? Or if there is better way of using different version on `Win7`?

Comment: For those who are looking for where py.exe is located,you can use `where py` in cmd

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It should be in the root directory of Python 3.3 installs and higher. It is not available for Python2.

Go to C:\PythonXX\ and you should find py.exe for your version.

In Command Prompt or your favorite shell (like Cygwin), run:

```
py -3.3 -m path/to/myscript.py
```

However, this only works if you have a 3.3 or higher installed.

EDIT: Anaconda does not come with Python launcher. It is only available for an ActiveState, standard, or probably many other installs.

EDIT2: Here are two brand-new, Python 3.4 installs of ActiveState Python and Anaconda Python, screenshotted. Notice how Anaconda Python does not include py.exe and a lot of other (non-essential) executables?

[image: Anaconda Install]
[image: ActiveState Install]

EDIT3: After some "difficult" testing, just set anaconda as your default install for Python3.4 and grab the py.exe from another install. That is all. So you can install Python3.4 from another source, uninstall it, and save the py.exe, make sure it is in the system path, and the python launcher is fully installed.

EDIT4: Actually there's also a standalone installer available here:
https://bitbucket.org/vinay.sajip/pylauncher/downloads

Comment: Hmm, your answer seems perhaps more useful than mine - not sure why it was downvoted.

Comment: Not sure but yours is useful. I just added screenshots to try to clarify this.

Comment: Then how can I install it? And is there anyother good distribution? I really like `Anaconda` comes with `Scipy`, makes python much more accssible for laymen like me.

Comment: There's a standalone installer available here:

https://bitbucket.org/vinay.sajip/pylauncher/downloads

Comment: This answer is ... blatantly not correct. The Python installer(s) put `py.exe` in `%SYSTEMROOT%`.

Comment: @Will, This answer is nearly 3 years old and tools change in much shorter periods. If information has changed in that time, you are free to update it with newer versions of software, or write a comment so I may do so. Your aggressive post stating that the information is blatantly incorrect completely ignores the time at which it was posted.

Answer (score 13):

If installing python from [python.org's downloads](https://www.python.org/downloads/) and you select "[x] install pylauncher [x] install for all users", `py.exe` is installed in `C:\Windows\py.exe` (`%SystemRoot%\py.exe`).

I think if you don't install for all users, then it's in the python install root.

If you are able to run `py` from `cmd.exe`, then you can find out where it is with `where py.exe`.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the python executable is part of the `conda` command if you're using Anaconda, according to their website. According to Alexander Huszagh (see his answer), the python *launcher* doesn't come with Anaconda python.

[Here is a blog post that is perhaps relevant.](http://continuum.io/blog/anaconda-python-3)

Comment: No. The Python launcher is py.exe which is found main directory in the standard install, as well as the ActiveState Python installs for Python 3.3 and later.

Comment: It doesn't come default, by the way.

Comment: "*It looks like the python executable is part of the conda command*", that would make sense as conda is used to select which "virtual" environment is activated (actually these virtual environments seem to be plain and redundant installations). How can the two cohabit? I wonder if life wouldn't be easier if conda was limited to configuration management, and the python launcher always used to select the right environment based on shebang lines.

Answer (score 2):

If NOT installed for ALL users, (python 3.11.3) it goes to:

C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Launcher\py.exe

Comment: C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311

Answer (score 1):

I first tried everything Alexander Huszagh has written. But none of it helped.

It took me a really long time to find the Python Launcher. I had accidentally changed how to open .py-files. And once you change it, you can't do right mouse click "Edit with IDLE" anymore. I eventually found them in the `C:\Windows\` directory named `py.exe`.