# py command not working but python command is working in cmd

Tags: python, django, cmd, pip

I have python version 3.8.0 and the .exe is added to the path but I am trying to create a django project and need to use py -m venv  command to create a virtual environment but it says py is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#launcher

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30794342/python-windows-where-is-the-python-launcher

Comment: When you say `the .exe is added to the path`, that's not what you're supposed to do! You don't add any files to `%PATH%`, only directories, so you're supposed to add the full path to the directory which contains `py.exe`, i.e its parent.

Answer (score 0):

Use:
python3 -m venv /path/to/new/virtual/environment
( more on virtualenv you will find there: https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html)

Answer (score 0):

Since the "python" command is working, your "python.exe" was added to PATH correctly. However, the "py" command is actually using `C:\Windows\py.exe` to be functioned.
Therefore, you need to add

> C:\Windows\

to **PATH** as well, to make the command "py" work as "python".