# Python command line -x option

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, python-3.x

I saw recently that python takes -x as a command line options which does what it explains in the docs here

```
python -x

Skip the first line of the source, allowing use of non-Unix forms of #!cmd. This is intended for a DOS specific hack only.
```

But, pardon me :) I don't really understand why someone would use a non-Unix form of #!cmd and even if it one does(for DOS) why skip it ?

Comment: Note the documentation is output of date, CPython hasn't supported MS-DOS in very long time. This is actually a Window-specific hack.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Start a Windows batch script (`.bat`/`.cmd`) with this first line:

```
@echo off & python -x "%~f0" %* & goto :eof
```

When you run it, `cmd.exe` will silently run `python -x` with the full file path to the script and the rest of the command-line arguments, then ignore the rest of the file. `python` will read the file, skipping the first line (which wouldn't parse as Python code), and treating the rest like a normal Python script.

This isn't necessary on UNIX-like platforms because you'd put

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

at the top of a script to get similar behavior, which looks like a comment to Python, so it continues executing through the rest of the file just fine.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.